# Prevent marker clustering with gmaps4rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

I am displaying 10 or so markers on google maps using gmaps4rails.  When the markers are close together, I get clustering.  I have set "do_clustering" to false, and I still get clustering.  Ideally, I would like to see every marker, no matter how close it is to another marker.  What is the easiest way to force this?
Cheers,
Tom

Update: I am using rails 2.3.11. gmaps4rails is 1.3.2.  I used the 2.3 instructions and overrode the gmaps4rails view.  I don't use gmappable, I just generate the json directly. 
The map options are:

```
@map_info = {
      :map_options => {
        :type => "ROADMAP",
        :center_longitude => 180,
        :zoom => 2,
        :auto_adjust => false,
        :do_clustering => false,
  }
}
```

Comment: Weird, what's your code and gem version?

Comment: I just tried it myself, and he's right, it does not seem to be working. (49640473947679dd088c30c3c044dc2bf17ba71b)

Comment: @Robin: you shoukd just pass the vlustering options in the markers hash

Comment: Right, it was in the markers options... I dont need to disable it, I was just trying to confirm his problem ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Markers , clustering options should be passed in the marker's options hash.

Simply :)

Comment: thank you, I like simple answers.  Do you have any thoughts on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618124/gmaps4rails-scaling-not-zooming-a-gmap? Is there a way to increase the size of a map without zooming?